# Dropify in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, dropify

I havle the following code:

```
<input type="file" class="dropify" required data-max-file-size="5M" :data-default-file="this.imageEdit"  />
                          

export default {
    props: ["item"],
    data() {
        return {
            nameEdit: '',
            imageEdit: '',
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.nameEdit = this.item.name;
        this.imageEdit = this.path
    }
};
```

I just want previously charge image, the url image is in  `this.imageEdit` but this  `:data-default-file="this.imageEdit"` is not working to me, in vue js I know that I can provider one variable using ':' before attribute, but it's not working why??